# How to calculate the total number of vertices (uniques or non uniques) in a grid?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I have a task that consists of calculating the number of vertices of N squares from a chessboard, but I have no idea of how to do it effectively

For example:

If I have 1 square of the board on the same line, my result would be 4, but if a have 2 squares, my result would be 6,

But if I have 2 squares on a line and 2 on the line below, the result would be 9, and so on. So it would be something like a grid structure and from there, count the number of total vertices

How to calculate the number of vertices of squares that overlap effectively?

Comment: As you've pointed out, the answer depends on how the squares are arranged. So are you looking for an algorithm that takes as input an arrangement of squares and computes the number of distinct corner points? Or are the arrangements always rectangles?

Comment: As Karl has said, you need to take examples : as it is presently written, your question is very ambiguous. If it is purely a **chessboard** with $n^2$ squares, there are $(n+1)^2$ vertices, but I don't think you address this question.